# create multiple files based on match words/pattern in python

Tags: python-3.x

i have a file that i need to create multiple files based on the word match

example of the file:

```
on AA by coder 
show run 
show ip int brief


on BB by coder
show int desc
show cdp neigh
```

expecting to get 2 files

1. AA.txt (contains show run and show ip int brief)
2. BB.txt (contains show int desc and show cdp neigh)

please advise how can we do it in Python.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the "with" and "write" functionality in Python:

```
user_input = input('Please input something here')
with (user_input + '.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(data)
```

Comment: i have a master file. thus there is no required to input.  thinking to use open the file and myfile.read.() and using keyword = coder. if match coder then generate a file. but still no idea how to match and generate a file

Comment: The `w` in the `with` function generates a file for you if one is not already present. The file is created in the same folder as the script. To match you can use a simple if statement `if keyword in variable`.